# Does a drain saddle need to be fully above the water line?

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

I'm connecting up a reverse osmosis system. There isn't much pipe available to install the drain saddle.

[image: diagram]

One candidate position (magenta box on the picture) is on the metal pipe coming out from the sink, which according to my calipers is about 1¼" OD. This seems to be *just* too small for the saddle. I have a piece of spare rubber from a bicycle handlebar mount that I could use to pack the other side of the saddle — would this be good or am I asking for leaks then?

The other position (green box) is potentially slightly below the water line of the U bend because of how far up the wall the drain connection is, and I'd also have to drill both the plastic and the metal pipe which extends inside it. I've marked the approx water line in blue (trying to take perspective into account).

It is the "Essence" system from APEC, which claims to be forced-drained rather than gravity-drained, so it seems like if it's slightly below it should be okay, but the instructions also say to install "above the trap". Should I reject the green site for this reason?

If it matters, it's a bathroom sink (it's in the middle of the house and we're mostly going to fill humidifiers from it), and the situation under the kitchen sink is even tighter.

Comment: @jsotola it’s due to perspective like I said, I understand how gravity works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it at the purple location.

If the front half of the saddle (with the hole) is too large a diameter for the pipe, and with the foam gasket it isn't a tight fit, then you can't use it.  But if it does fit snugly, but the back half touches it before becoming tight enough,  you can pad the back out with anything.  Foam pipe insulation might be better than the thin rubber you're considering.

Look for a saddle clamp that fits.

An alternative would be to replace the tail piece with one that has a dishwasher inlet.  You would have to hack together a somewhat inelegant adapter from your little tube to the bigger inlet, using a quick-connect-to-female-garden-hose adapter, a garden hose male end, a short length of garden hose, and a hose clamp.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Alternately there's [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08YP9VKHZ) ready-made kit that includes the quick connect and the necessary things to connect it to your tail piece via a short piece of hose.  BUT it also includes another inlet for an actual dishwasher, that you'd have to cap off.

[image]

Comment: Very thorough, thanks! I like the metal tail piece with dishwasher idea.